# PHP error with adminclass ts3

Tags: php, class, frameworks

What is the problem with this code?
I want to make a dashboard for webinterface. I dont want use others stuff. When i try it its shows me errors. I cant understand it what is the problem with this code.

```
<?php 
        $virtualserver_name = 0;
        require("ts3admin.class.php");
        $ts3_ip = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
        $ts3_queryport = 10011;
        $ts3_user = 'serveradmin';
        $ts3_pass = '********';
        $ts3_port = $row['serverPort'];
        $ts3_sid = $row['serverId'];
        $tsAdmin = new ts3admin($ts3_ip, $ts3_queryport);
        $server = $tsAdmin->serverInfo($ts3_sid, sid, true);
        if (isset($_POST['stop']))
        {
            $tsAdmin->getElement('success', $tsAdmin->connect());
            $tsAdmin->login($ts3_user, $ts3_pass);
            $tsAdmin->serverStop($ts3_sid);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['start']))
        {
            $tsAdmin->getElement('success', $tsAdmin->connect());
            $tsAdmin->login($ts3_user, $ts3_pass);
            $tsAdmin->serverStart($ts3_sid);
        }
        echo "Szerver státusza: ";
        $serverInfo = $tsAdmin->serverInfo();
        if ($serverInfo['virtualserver_status'] = "online"){
          echo "<font color=green>Online</font></br>";
        }else{
          echo "<font color=red>Offline</font></br>";
        }
        echo $serverInfo['virtualserver_name'];
        ?>
```

Its shows me this: `Undefined index: virtualserver_name in path\to\file.php on line 35`
Somebody can help me?

Comment: As it says, the variable with `virtualserver_name` doesn't exists. To debug what's stored in `$serverInfo` simply do this: `var_dump($serverInfo);`. This will show information about wich keys are available for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Line 35 of your file tries to access `$serverInfo['virtualserver_status']`, which is an array. Your method does not find a key-value-pair with the key "virtualserver_status", so it might not be set.

Comment: virtualserver_status is it in ts3admin.class.php as function is it not good?